# Bootstrap form not displaying inline

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

have a pop-up modal I'm trying to put an inline form in. Unfortunately, although I'm following bootstrap's suggestions on their doc, it's not displaying inline. When I put it on fiddle.js, it works perfectly. Scratching my head as to why this isn't working.

Here's the code:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <input class="required" style="" placeholder="where should I send it?"></input>
  <input type="submit" class="button-main" value="download"></input>
</form>
```

The form is here: http://jackalopemedia.com/exp (click on "sign me up")

Here's the fiddle with it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/h3Ds4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" class="button-main" value="download"></input>
```

Should be

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="download">
```

`btn-default` is interchangeable with whatever other btn you'd like to use as shown here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

Comment: great...would be much appreciated if you could upvote and/or accept, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Make sure you are using the correct markup](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```